# On hover in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On hover it shows dd. It's working fine, but the problem is I am not able to click in dd. If I move dd, it's hiding. How do I fix this?

#### HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.navigation dd').hide();

        $('.navigation dt').hover(function(){
            $(this).next('dd').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to 'drag and drop'?

Comment: sorry i am not good at javascript can you please give me example

Comment: 'drag and drop', like you do a Windows icon.

Comment: can you please give me any example but i need on hover only

Comment: instread of `hover` use `mouseenter`. it will work.

Comment: if mouseenter then only it hide otherwise it's keep on show only

Answer (score 0):

You may use your code like this

```
  $('.navigation').hover(function(){ 
    $(this).find('dd').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).find('dt').toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 
  });
```

Comment: `slow` only give you to time to click the dd. not a effective idea

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that effect in pure CSS, which will always outperform JS:

```js
$('dd').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})
$('.navigation dt').hover(function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 
});
```

```css
dt, dd {height: 50px; background: green; color: white; margin: 0}
dd {height: 0; transition: all 0.2s linear; overflow: hidden; background: blue}
dt:hover + dd, dd:hover {height: 50px}
dd.clicked {background: yellow; color: black}
dt.glace_navigationlayer-collapsed {color: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <dt>This is DT, hover me</dt>
  <dd>This is DD, click me</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: You can still use JS to add a class, but keep CSS for animation. Just a suggestion. Note that you can also click DD now.

Comment: Added the class change on hover.

Comment: But class didn't add

Comment: "Which will always outperform JS", that's a bold statement, and also not always true.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: if i set height auto this also transition: all 0.2s linear not working

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'm yet to see a single example of JS animations even coming close to CSS animations in terms of performance. Of course, I'm not talking about how much more complex the JS animations can be, but just a comparison between those that CSS actually can do.

Comment: Anything beyond the trivial transition or cyclic animation will be far far more performant and easy to write with JS than with CSS. Practically all modern animation libraries are written in JS and have no CSS in them for that reason.

Comment: As I said, I was referring the things that CSS **can** do, and it will always kill JS in that scope (I'd love to see an example that proves otherwise). I guess you can call that trivial transitions/cyclic animations because doing anything more complex in CSS is a suicide.

Comment: @MagentoDev `height: auto` won't work for transitions because it needs a number for interpolation. The other answer, with the hover listener on the navigation element, will do what you want with your original code, my is just a suggestion.